# Uninitialized Constant in console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I am having some issues in console with a new Rails 6 app. The server (puma) works fine.

In my gemfile:

`gem 'connection_pool'`

It is bundled.

Load console:

`ConnectionPool::Wrapper.new(size: 1, timeout: 3)`

Gives me `NameError (uninitialized constant ConnectionPool)`

But the code runs fine when it is hit via the server.

I have restarted and reloaded 100 times. I know it is something stupid, but I can't figure it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try requiring the file in console,

`require 'connection_pool'`

And then try `ConnectionPool::Wrapper.new(size: 1, timeout: 3)`

You can also try stopping spring, Run `spring stop` in application home path to reload everything again

Hope that helps!